# How do "Pay to Script Hash" transactions work?

Tags: script, p2sh

[BIP16](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0016.mediawiki) gives the following example to explain "Pay to Script Hash":

```
scriptSig:    [signature] {[pubkey] OP_CHECKSIG}
scriptPubKey: OP_HASH160 [20-byte-hash of {[pubkey] OP_CHECKSIG} ] OP_EQUAL
```

But I don't get what's happening here. I've tried executing the script on paper (and assumed the parts in squared/curly brackets are treated as constants):

1. `[signature]` and `{[pubkey] OP_CHECKSIG}` are pushed onto the stack
2. `OP_HASH160` hashes `{[pubkey] OP_CHECKSIG}`
3. The same hash comes from the `scriptPubKey` onto the stack
4. Consequently `OP_EQUAL` gives `True`
5. The `[signature]` is not checked at all!

If the `{[pubkey] OP_CHECKSIG}` is executed, the scriptSig would only give `True`, which makes even less sense.

To frame a clear question: How do "Pay to Script Hash" scripts work, especially this example case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're correct so far, you just stopped before you were finished. As BIP16 says, it "defines additional validation rules that apply only to the new transactions" -- specifically, "{serialized script} is popped off the initial stack, and the transaction is validated again using the popped stack and the deserialized script as the scriptPubKey."

So:

1) The script is popped off the stack, leaving only `[signature]` on the stack.

2) The deserialized script is added, leaving `[signature] [pubkey] OP_CHECKSIG`.

2) The transaction is validated again, that is, a normal signature verification occurs against the specified public key.

Comment: i'd like a more comprehensive walkthrough, or a link to one. i still don't get it.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question at all as to how the pushed script bytes get executed. I assume BIP16 defies somewhere in it's complex language a definition for how the network identifies a "serialized script", since it is just data. Why would signatures, public keys, etc not be attempted to be interpreted as scripts as well given this definition?